# Move class to another class on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, responsive, move

I have the following structure:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="text1">...</div>
</div>

<div class="aside">
   <div class="text2">...</div>
</div>
```

Is it possible when user is using mobile to get this structure:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="text2">...</div> (should be on top place)
   <div class="text1">...</div>
</div>

<div class="aside"> (this class can be hidden)

</div>
```

I do not prefer the option with display: none/block. Is there way to do this with javascript?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes. This is possible and many libraries (like Twitter Bootstrap etc.) bring solutions for this. There are several ways to solve your problem, you need to get familiar to "responsive design". This question is way too broad....

Comment: I'am using wordpress.. And my template has conflicts with bootstrap.

Comment: You could try using CSS media queries to change style of classes (for example show/hide them) based on the width of screen

Answer (score 0):

This would be an easy approach in jQuery, but as @messerbill already mentioned, I would recommend you, to use responsive CSS frameworks such as Bootstrap or Bulma.

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
  $(".text2").prependTo(".container");
}
```

**CodePen**: https://codepen.io/dmnktoe/pen/GzwQaR